# C# regex for English char and non-English

Tags: c#, regex

I use this `^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$` regex for name validator according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx).

Now I want add NON-English characters to this.

How I can do this?

Comment: `^[\p{L}'\s-]{1,40}$`

Comment: Use a word `^(?:[^\W_\d]|[\s'-]){1,40}$` A side note, the msdn link is to a regex that will match `''''''''''`. If that's a valid name I would be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support all BMP and astral planes, you need both `\p{L}` (all letters) and `\p{M}` (all diacritics) Unicode category classes:

```
^[\p{L}\p{M}\s'-]{1,40}$
```

Note that `\p{L}` already includes `[a-zA-Z]`, and all lower- and uppercase letters.

Or, since `\s` matches newlines (I doubt you really need newline symbols to match), you can use `\p{Zs}` - Unicode separator class (various kinds of spaces):

```
^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Zs}'-]{1,40}$
```

Placing the hyphen at the end is just best practice, although it would be handled as  a literal hyphen in your regex, too.

Comment: Also, please see [Unicode Categories at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category): *To match a letter including any diacritics, use `\p{L}\p{M}*+`.*. So, it is a good idea to include that class in the regex, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^[\p{L}'\s-]{1,40}$
```

Note that \p{L} is Unicode property and it matches everything that has the property letter.